# How to calculate time needed through multiple routes?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

For example, with input like:

```
4 6 7
1 2 6 2
......//more routes statement same format as second line
1 4
```

It means there are 4 places in total, and 6 routes in total, with 7cm convex hull of the ship(From the first line). The next 6 lines states where does the route connect, time needed and how many cm of the hull were worn down in the process. (In the second line, the route connects 1 and , takes 6 minutes, and wore down the hull by 2. The last line states where the starting point and destination are (1 and 4 in this case). The goal for this program is to get the minimum time used with the hull not completely worn down. I had tried using a

```
map(starting point of a route, end point);
```

but I can't really assign time used or the number of hull worn down this way, since multiple route can have the same starting point, meaning the two locations can't be used as a key like

```
map(starting point, time);
```

Also

```
Matrix[boolean][boolean]
```

doesn't seem to be an effective way to do this question. What technique should I use for this program and how do I do it?
Complete example with input:

```
10 4 7
1 2 4 4
1 3 7 2
3 1 8 1
3 2 2 2
4 2 1 6
3 4 1 1
1 4 6 12
1 4
```

output:

```
7
```

The routes can be used in two directions.

Comment: Is this a variant on the Traveling Salesman Problem?

Comment: Sort of, but you don't have to visit each city, just needs to go to the destination.

Comment: So basically each vertex has two cost-metrics associated with it: time to travel that edge and hull-wear. And all you need is the path with the minimum traveled time such that the cost according to the second path-cost (hull wear) doesn't get beyond a threshold? Sounds rather like a modification of Dijkstra than TSP to me.

Comment: @Paul Yes, that's probably a better way to look at it

Comment: @Spano best idea that comes to my would be backtracking though. Indeed an interesting problem. I'll see if I can come up with anything that gets better than plain backtracking, but I doubt it to be honest.

Comment: Is the complete example correct? There seem to be only 4 places, not 10, with 6 routes between them (1 bidirectional: 1-3 and 3-1), not 4. The only legal path seems to be 1-3-4, which takes time 8 and causes wear 3. And what do you mean by "the routes can be used in two directions"? Do routes that are only mentioned once have the same weights in both directions, and routes that are mentioned twice have different weights in each direction?